# What does the following cronjob stand for?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, sphinx

I have this cronjob which Sphinx is recommending I run:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/wp-content/uploads/sphinx/cron/cron_reindex_delta.php
5 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/wp-content/uploads/sphinx/cron/cron_reindex_main.php
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/wp-content/uploads/sphinx/cron/cron_reindex_stats.php
```

I've looked up a little bit about cronjobs but I couldn't find what does those forward slashes mean in the above command. Does the 1st and 3rd command run every five hours of each day and the 2nd command run every five days? If I'm wrong, please tell me what the is the correct interpretation.

Thanks

Comment: This migth help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

So:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/wp-content/uploads/sphinx/cron/cron_reindex_delta.php
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/wp-content/uploads/sphinx/cron/cron_reindex_stats.php
```

every 5 min.

```
5 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/wp-content/uploads/sphinx/cron/cron_reindex_main.php
```

every day at `0.05`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't quite get the last part. What do you mean by "every hour 0 and minute 5"? What does that mean

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't a very good way to explain it from my side :) Rephrased to `every day at 0.05`.

Comment: So basically everyday at 12:05 A.M? e.g. five minutes after midnight?

Comment: Yes, exactly @user2028856